# Rails 3 and ActiveAdmin: to_s vs. display_name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to get my head around Rails and ActiveAdmin, and string representations of objects. Particularly, I'm struggling to define a single method that'll get picked up by Rails (in the templates) and ActiveAdmin.

If I do something like:

```
def to_s
  "Hello world"
end
```

Then that works in Rails. But not in ActiveAdmin, which only picks it up if I use `display_name`. It's solved by doing this:

```
alias_attribute :to_s, :display_name
```

But is that a bit hacky? Just wondering if I've missed something obvious. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the end, I used:

```
def display_name
  "#{name}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

What about calling the method something else like

```
def something
  "Hello World"
end
```

and then calling...

alias_attribute :something

Perhaps there is a conflict with calling the method to_s in this case?

Comment: I think you've misunderstood `alias_attribute`, which takes two arguments - new, and old.

Comment: Probably have, worth a punt! :)